# Why does my clock widget occupies a lot of memory in CACHED PROCESSES? How I can solve?

Tags: android, process, widget, memcached

I created a clock widget that is a simple `ImageView` that shows a `Bitmap` created every minute.

The widget is updated from service that implements a `BroadcastReceiver` to get time updates using `ACTION_TIME_TICK`. I didn't find other solutions. Is this the best?

After some minutes, if I click on `"SHOW CACHED PROCESSES"` (in settings/apps/running) my widgets will occupies about 200 mb of memory and I don't know why.

There is a way to free this memory?

This is a part of widget code:

```
public class Widget_01_Clock extends AppWidgetProvider {

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {

    Bitmap bmpClock = WidgetPaint.getClockBitmap(String textTime, 100, Color.White); 
    RemoteViews updateViews = new  RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.w_01_clock);    
    updateViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.w_01_clock, bmpClock);
    bmpClock.recycle();    

    }
}
```

Code to make the bitmap of the clock

```
public Bitmap getClockBitmap(String textTime, float textSize, int textColor) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setTextSize(textSize);
    paint.setColor(textColor);
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(),typeface);
    paint.setTypeface(tf);
    int width = (int) (paint.measureText(text) + 0.5f); // round
    float baseline = (int) (paint.ascent() + 0.5f);
    int height = (int) (baseline + paint.descent() + 0.5f);
    Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(image);
    canvas.drawText(text, 0, baseline, paint);
    return image;
}
```

Many thanks at all.

Comment: What's the code for `WidgetPaint.getClockBitmap()`?